# How to run .exe created on Visual Studio for MAC

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I developed an application using the Visual Studio 209 for MAC that generates a .exe file as a result.

I would like to know how can I run this .exe file without the VS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Winebottler on Mac that provides environment to run windows based applications.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!

The point is, I've developed on MAC and I wanna run this application in another MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late for this but this could help another user looking for the same thing.

You can use the terminal to run that `.exe` file by using `mono` or `mono64`:

For example: `mono myProgram.exe`

*UPDATE:*

You can create a Unix Executable file with mono command `mkbundle` (see documentation here: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/mkbundle/)

For example: `mkbundle -o MyProgram --simple myProgram.exe`